# I can't access my array elements outside a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the function everything is going smooth inside the for loop. however, I can't access the elements of the return array in other functions or outside the for loop. The values are there but not accessible. Checking the length of the returned array gives me 0.

```
function getDiagonalPositions(coins){
    let king = false;
    let movingPositionsAll = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
        let movingPositions = [];
        let coinAndMovingPositions = [];
        if(!king){
            if(((parseInt(coins[i][1]))) > 0 && ((parseInt(coins[i][1])) != 7)){                  
                nextMovefirst = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) - 1));
                nextMovesecond = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) + 1));
            }
            else if ((parseInt(coins[i][1])) <= 0){
                nextMovefirst = '';
                nextMovesecond = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) + 1));
            }
            else {
                nextMovefirst = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) - 1));
                nextMovesecond = '';
            }
            movingPositions.push(nextMovefirst);
            movingPositions.push(nextMovesecond);
            coinAndMovingPositions.push(coins[i]);
            let positions = movingPositions.filter(function (el) {return el; });
            coinAndMovingPositions.push(positions);
            movingPositionsAll.push(coinAndMovingPositions);
        }
    }
    console.log(movingPositionsAll);
    return movingPositionsAll; 
}
```

Comment: Use the `return` or why else are you returning it? `let whatever = getDiagonalPositions(coins)`.

Comment: please create a sandbox for it .

Comment: how do you know they are "there but not accessible"? Can you show us the code which tries to access them?

Comment: You should add the code where you try to "access the elements of the return array" or else we can't know what you want to achieve. The fact that the var `king` is never set in the function makes one think you try to interact between functions the wrong way (`king` could be declared outside of the function to be visible by others, but most probably it should be an argument of the function itself).

Comment: Now it is working properly. I just removed a setTimeOut function defined somewhere. And the problem solved. But thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing something, I don't see any difference in printing inside or outside.

```js
 function getDiagonalPositions(coins){
            let king = false;
            let movingPositionsAll = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
                let movingPositions = [];
                let coinAndMovingPositions = [];
                if(!king){
                    if(((parseInt(coins[i][1]))) > 0 && ((parseInt(coins[i][1])) != 7)){                  
                        nextMovefirst = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) - 1));
                        nextMovesecond = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) + 1));
                    }
                    else if ((parseInt(coins[i][1])) <= 0){
                        nextMovefirst = '';
                        nextMovesecond = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) + 1));
                    }
                    else {
                        nextMovefirst = (parseInt(coins[i][0] - 1) + '' + (parseInt(coins[i][1]) - 1));
                        nextMovesecond = '';
                    }
                    movingPositions.push(nextMovefirst);
                    movingPositions.push(nextMovesecond);
                    coinAndMovingPositions.push(coins[i]);
                    let positions = movingPositions.filter(function (el) {return el; });
                    coinAndMovingPositions.push(positions);
                    movingPositionsAll.push(coinAndMovingPositions);
                }
            }
            console.log('Inside',movingPositionsAll);
            return movingPositionsAll; 
        }

      var output = getDiagonalPositions([['0','1']])
        console.log('Outside',output)
```